# Deploy nginx official image, the volumn mount incorrectly

Tags: nginx, docker, kubernetes

Deploy nginx official image, the volumn can't mount correctly. The volume named nginx-content was mounted to /etc/nginx/conf instead of /usr/share/www/html.
Any response will be appreciated.

The content of yaml file:

```
[root@kube-master ~]# cat pv-nginx-con*
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 172.19.180.221
    path: /nginxstandlone/conf
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nginx-content
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 172.19.180.221
    path: /nginxstandlone/content
[root@kube-master ~]# cat nginx
nginx-php7-gwr1.0.yaml  nginx-php7.yaml         nginxstandone_one.yaml  nginxstandone.yaml      
[root@kube-master ~]# cat nginxstandone.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nginx-content
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-standlone
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8383
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30065
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: nginx-standlone
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-standlone-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: nginx-standlone
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-standlone
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-standlone
        image: docker.io/nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: nginx-conf
            mountPath: "/etc/nginx"
          - name: nginx-content
            mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-conf
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-conf
      - name: nginx-content
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-content
[root@kube-master ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in slack.
    barak_a [7:20 PM] 
    1. delete all of them

```
[7:21]  
2. create PV of content

[7:21]  
3. create PVC of content

gwrcn [7:21 PM] 
thanks

barak_a [7:21 PM] 
4.create PV conf
5. create PVC conf

gwrcn [7:21 PM] 
i'll follow your guide

barak_a [7:22 PM] 
tell me if you solve it

gwrcn [7:22 PM] 
ok,i do right now

gwrcn [7:31 PM] 
it work like a charm

[7:31]  
thanks
```